# Postgres from unix shell out put not appear in Log

Tags: postgresql, shell, unix

I am writing a batch job for Postgres for first time. I have return ".sh" file, which has a command with out any out put in the log or console.

Code

```
export PGPASSWORD=<password>
psql -h <host> -p <port> -U <user> -d <database> --file cleardata.sql > log\cleardata.log 2>&1
```

What I did at cammond line

su postgres

and run ./cleardatasetup.sh

Nothing is happening.

Please note : When I try psql command in Unix command line, I am getting message as some SQL exception which is valid.

Can any one please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably wanted to create `log/cleardata.log` but you have a backslash where you need a slash. You will find that the result is a file named `log\cleardata.log` instead.

The backslash is just a regular character in the file's name, but it's special to the shell, so you'll need to quote or escape it to (unambiguously) manipulate it from the shell;

```
ls -l log\\cleardata.log  # escaped
mv 'log\cleardata.log' log/cleardata.log  # quoted
```